# Why does it appear "1:powershell" at terminal in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal, react-router

Why does it appear "1:powershell" at terminal in react.js?

[image]
[image]

Comment: ...because it's your first terminal, and it's running powershell?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change this:

1. Open Visual Studio Code and press and hold Ctrl + ` to open the terminal.
2. Open the command palette using Ctrl + Shift + P .
3. Type - Select Default Profile.
4. Select your prefered terminal from the options (zsh/bash/ect).
5. Click on the + icon in the terminal window.
   The new terminal now will be your prefered terminal (zsh/bash/ect).